# How can I get a list of all functions stored in the database of a particular schema in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, function

I want to be able to connect to a PostgreSQL database and find all of the functions for a particular schema.

My thought was that I could make some query to pg_catalog or information_schema and get a list of all functions, but I can't figure out where the names and parameters are stored. I'm looking for a query that will give me the function name and the parameter types it takes (and what order it takes them in).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

After some searching, I was able to find the **`information_schema.routines`** table and the **`information_schema.parameters`** tables. Using those, one can construct a query for this purpose. LEFT JOIN, instead of JOIN, is necessary to retrieve functions without parameters.

```
SELECT routines.routine_name, parameters.data_type, parameters.ordinal_position
FROM information_schema.routines
    LEFT JOIN information_schema.parameters ON routines.specific_name=parameters.specific_name
WHERE routines.specific_schema='my_specified_schema_name'
ORDER BY routines.routine_name, parameters.ordinal_position;
```

Comment: You will find `oidvectortypes` really useful too. See new answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24034604/398670

Comment: The code above will not show all functions, You need a LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN to also show functions with no input parameters.

Answer (score 259):

```
\df <schema>.*
```

in [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) gives the necessary information.

To see the query that's used internally connect to a database with `psql` and supply an extra "`-E`" (or "`--echo-hidden`") option and then execute the above command.

Comment: Could you paste in what that query is?

Comment: SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  p.proname as "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as "Result data type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as "Argument data types",
 CASE
  WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
  WHEN p.proiswindow THEN 'window'
  WHEN p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype THEN 'trigger'
  ELSE 'normal'
 END as "Type"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE n.nspname ~ '^(public)$'
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;

Above is the query generated (from \set ECHO_HIDDEN 'on').

Comment: A problem with this approach is that the query is generated for a specific version of Postgres, and might fail for other versions. For instance, on Postgres 11 you get `ERROR:  column p.proisagg does not exist`.

Comment: thanks for the mention of `--echo-hidden`, this is certainly super helpful

Comment: by running `\c ma_database` then `set search_path to my_schema;`, command `\df` do the job !

Answer (score 43):

There's a handy function, `oidvectortypes`, that makes this a lot easier.

```
SELECT format('%I.%I(%s)', ns.nspname, p.proname, oidvectortypes(p.proargtypes)) 
FROM pg_proc p INNER JOIN pg_namespace ns ON (p.pronamespace = ns.oid)
WHERE ns.nspname = 'my_namespace';
```

Credit to [Leo Hsu and Regina Obe at Postgres Online](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/74-How-to-delete-many-functions.html) for pointing out `oidvectortypes`. I wrote similar functions before, but used complex nested expressions that this function gets rid of the need for.

[See related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24034539/398670).

---

(edit in 2016)

Summarizing typical report options:

```
-- Compact:
SELECT format('%I.%I(%s)', ns.nspname, p.proname, oidvectortypes(p.proargtypes))

-- With result data type: 
SELECT format(
       '%I.%I(%s)=%s', 
       ns.nspname, p.proname, oidvectortypes(p.proargtypes),
       pg_get_function_result(p.oid)
)

-- With complete argument description: 
SELECT format('%I.%I(%s)', ns.nspname, p.proname, pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid))

-- ... and mixing it.

-- All with the same FROM clause:
FROM pg_proc p INNER JOIN pg_namespace ns ON (p.pronamespace = ns.oid)
WHERE ns.nspname = 'my_namespace';
```

**NOTICE**:  use `p.proname||'_'||p.oid AS specific_name`  to obtain unique names, or to JOIN with `information_schema` tables — see `routines` and `parameters` at  @RuddZwolinski's answer.

---

The function's  [*OID*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) (see `pg_catalog.pg_proc`) and the function's *specific_name* (see `information_schema.routines`) are the main reference options to functions. Below, some useful functions in reporting and other contexts.

```
--- --- --- --- ---
--- Useful overloads: 

CREATE FUNCTION oidvectortypes(p_oid int) RETURNS text AS $$
    SELECT oidvectortypes(proargtypes) FROM pg_proc WHERE oid=$1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION oidvectortypes(p_specific_name text) RETURNS text AS $$
    -- Extract OID from specific_name and use it in oidvectortypes(oid).
    SELECT oidvectortypes(proargtypes) 
    FROM pg_proc WHERE oid=regexp_replace($1, '^.+?([^_]+)$', '\1')::int;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION pg_get_function_arguments(p_specific_name text) RETURNS text AS $$
    -- Extract OID from specific_name and use it in pg_get_function_arguments.
    SELECT pg_get_function_arguments(regexp_replace($1, '^.+?([^_]+)$', '\1')::int)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

--- --- --- --- ---
--- User customization: 

CREATE FUNCTION pg_get_function_arguments2(p_specific_name text) RETURNS text AS $$
    -- Example of "special layout" version.
    SELECT trim(array_agg( op||'-'||dt )::text,'{}') 
    FROM (
        SELECT data_type::text as dt, ordinal_position as op
        FROM information_schema.parameters 
        WHERE specific_name = p_specific_name 
        ORDER BY ordinal_position
    ) t
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: The `proname` is the name, but how to get the OID for, eg. use in `pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(oid))`?

Comment: @PeterKrauss The `oid` column of `pg_proc`. It's a hidden column.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25388031/161040 for how to exclude extension-dependent functions (e.g. functions from PostGIS).

Answer (score 40):

If any one is interested here is what query is executed by `psql` on postgres 9.1:

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  p.proname as "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as "Result data type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as "Argument data types",
 CASE
  WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
  WHEN p.proiswindow THEN 'window'
  WHEN p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype THEN 'trigger'
  ELSE 'normal'
 END as "Type"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid)
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;
```

You can get what `psql` runs for a backslash command by running `psql` with the `-E` flag.

Comment: Just came across your answer and tried the query on Postgres 11.5. It says: `ERROR:  column p.proisagg does not exist`

Comment: Thanks for this; the two top-voted answers didn't show my function!

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek this is for < 11 for 11+ use `p.prokind = 'a'` for agg and `p.prokind = 'w' for window

Comment: For those who need a bit more handholding, replace the first two WHEN lines above with:
  WHEN p.prokind = 'a' THEN 'agg'
  WHEN p.prokind = 'w' THEN 'window'

Answer (score 27):

Run below SQL query to create a view which will show all functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW show_functions AS
    SELECT routine_name FROM information_schema.routines 
        WHERE routine_type='FUNCTION' AND specific_schema='public';
```

Answer (score 26):

***Get List of function_schema and function_name...***

---

```sql
SELECT
    n.nspname AS function_schema,
    p.proname AS function_name
FROM
    pg_proc p
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON p.pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE
    n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
ORDER BY
    function_schema,
    function_name;
```

Answer (score 11):

Is a good idea named the functions with commun alias on the first words for filtre the name with `LIKE`
Example with public schema in Postgresql 9.4, be sure to replace with his scheme

```
SELECT routine_name 
FROM information_schema.routines 
WHERE routine_type='FUNCTION' 
  AND specific_schema='public'
  AND routine_name LIKE 'aliasmyfunctions%';
```

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
perfdb-# \df information_schema.*;

List of functions
        Schema      |        Name        | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  
 information_schema | _pg_char_max_length   | integer | typid oid, typmod integer | normal
 information_schema | _pg_char_octet_length | integer | typid oid, typmod integer | normal
 information_schema | _pg_datetime_precision| integer | typid oid, typmod integer | normal
 .....
 information_schema | _pg_numeric_scale     | integer | typid oid, typmod integer | normal
 information_schema | _pg_truetypid         | oid     | pg_attribute, pg_type     | normal
 information_schema | _pg_truetypmod        | integer | pg_attribute, pg_type     | normal
(11 rows)
```

Comment: An how is that different to Milen's answer?

Comment: This is not a query, its a command of the `psql` Postgres client interface. This will only work in `psql` and is not technically a SQL query.

Answer (score 4):

This function returns all user defined routines in current database.

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) FROM pg_proc p
INNER JOIN pg_namespace ns ON p.pronamespace = ns.oid
WHERE ns.nspname = 'public';
```

Answer (score 2):

Here’s my adaptation of Rudd Zwolinski’s answer, which gives three columns with function **name, parameter names,** and **return type**:

```
SELECT 
  routines.routine_name AS name,
  ARRAY_AGG(parameter_name) AS parameter_names,
  routines.data_type AS return_type
FROM information_schema.routines
LEFT JOIN information_schema.parameters ON (routines.specific_name = parameters.specific_name)
WHERE routine_type = 'FUNCTION' AND routine_schema = 'public'
GROUP BY routines.routine_name, routines.data_type
ORDER BY routines.routine_name;
```

Output example:

| name | parameter_names | return_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| add_user | {userid, password, username} | boolean |
| edit_user | {userid, email, firstname, lastname, phone} | boolean |

Answer (score 1):

The joins in abovementioned answers returns not only input parameters, but also outputs. So it is necessary to specify also *parameter_mode*. This select will return list of functions with its input parametrs (if having some). Postgres 14.

```
select r.routine_name, array_agg(p.data_type::text order by p.ordinal_position) from information_schema.routines r left join information_schema.parameters p on r.specific_name = p.specific_name
where r.routine_type = 'FUNCTION' and r.specific_schema = 'schema_name' and (p.parameter_mode = 'IN' or p.parameter_mode is null)
group by r.routine_name order by r.routine_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have extended one of the codes by the comment. I am using this for documentation purpose.

```
SELECT
    n.nspname as "Schema",
    p.proname as "Name",
    pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as "Returns",
    pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as "Parameters",
    des.description as "Comment"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
    LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
    LEFT JOIN (select * from pg_catalog.pg_description where objsubid = 0) des ON des.objoid = p.oid
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid)
    AND n.nspname = 'my_schema'
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

[cli npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nitra/pg-reassign-owner):

```bash
  PGHOST=localhost \
  PGUSER=process.env.USER \
  PGDATABASE=process.env.USER \
  PGPASSWORD=null \
  PGPORT=5432 \
  npx @nitra/pg-reassign-owner NEW_DB_OWNER
```

Reassign all objects in database (process.env.PGDATABASE) to new owner (NEW_DB_OWNER)