# How to get the list of functions in database in PostgreSQL along with its parameters?

Tags: function, postgresql, permissions, plpgsql

I have a database which has over 1000 functions. I want to GRANT execution permission to certain users. I can't do it manually, therefore I want to get a list of functions and write a code to generate the GRANT EXECUTE script for all the functions. I tried the following script but this is not giving me the parameters. I am unable to get the parameters with this query.

```
SELECT  'GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION '||nspname||'.'||proname||' TO gis;'
FROM    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN    pg_catalog.pg_proc p
ON      pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE   nspname = 'ccdb'
```

How can I get my desired result with the datatypes?

Like,

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION <schema_name>.<table_name>(<list of arguments>) TO <user_name>;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1347282/398670

Comment: I have seen that post, but there I am not able to get the list of my arguments that I have for my functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a handy function to help you out: `oidvectortypes`.

```
SELECT format('%I.%I(%s)', ns.nspname, p.proname, oidvectortypes(p.proargtypes)) 
FROM pg_proc p INNER JOIN pg_namespace ns ON (p.pronamespace = ns.oid);
```

shows all functions with arguments. You can adapt that `format` incantation to generate any desired statements, and if you like, `LOOP` over it to feed the generated statement into `EXECUTE` in PL/PgSQL.

Credit to [Leo Hsu and Regina Obe at Postgres Online](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/74-How-to-delete-many-functions.html) for pointing out `oidvectortypes`. I wrote similar functions before, but used complex nested expressions that this function gets rid of the need for.

Note that in this case *you don't have to do any custom SQL generation at all*, though. [Just use `GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA myschema TO ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) if you're on a vaguely recent PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot Craig. This has been of great help for me. :)

Comment: GRANT ... ON ALL FUNCTIONS! Sweet.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [pg_get_function_arguments(func_oid).](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-info.html) Dynamic GRANT must be executed in anonymous code block or function (change *my_schema* and *my_username* to actual values):

```
do $$
declare
    funcdef text;
begin
    for funcdef in
        select format('%s.%s (%s)', 
            nspname, proname, pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid))
        from pg_proc p
        join pg_namespace n on pronamespace = n.oid
        where nspname = 'my_schema' 
        and not proisagg
    loop
        execute format ('GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION %s TO my_username', funcdef);
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that's the better thing to use over `oidvectortypes`.

Comment: This too is a nice option!