# How can I take only all functions backup in postgreSQL using PGADMIN 9.6?

Tags: postgresql

I need to take all functions backup from postgreSQL using Pgadmin 4. I can't find any solutions far taking all functions backup, I have tried one solution but it returns only one function.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with PgAdmin 4 but you can do it with a query. See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347282/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-functions-stored-in-the-database-of-a-particular-sch).

Answer (score 1):

To create a script with the definitions of all functions in schema `schemaname`, you could use:

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef(f.oid) || E';\n'
FROM pg_proc f
   JOIN pg_namespace n ON f.pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE n.nspname = 'schemaname';
```