# Postgresql RIGHT function giving an error

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    purchase_order_master.po1_num AS "PO #", 
    RIGHT(purchase_order_history.poh1_gl, 2) AS "Dept",
    purchase_order_history.poh1_gl,
    purchase_order_master.po1_podate AS "PO Date", 
    purchase_order_history.poh1_gl AS "GL Account #", 
    purchase_order_master.po1_dept, 
    purchase_order_master.po1_vname AS "Vendor Name", 
    purchase_order_master.po1_vnum AS "Vendor Number"
    
FROM
    purchase_order_master
    INNER JOIN
    purchase_order_line_items
    ON 
        purchase_order_master.po1_num = purchase_order_line_items.po2_num AND
        purchase_order_master.po1_arid = purchase_order_line_items.po2_arid
    INNER JOIN
    purchase_order_history
    ON 
        purchase_order_line_items.po2_num = purchase_order_history.poh1_ponum AND
        purchase_order_line_items.po2_arid = purchase_order_history.poh1_arid
ORDER BY
 "PO Date" DESC;
```

Gives error:

> ERROR:  function right(numeric, integer) does not exist
> LINE 3:  RIGHT(purchase_order_history.poh1_gl, 2) AS Dept,
> ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type >casts.

Do I need to change the column values before I try?

Comment: I'm trying to grab the last two characters from the poh1_g1 column.

Comment: With explicit cast to string: `RIGHT(purchase_order_history.poh1_gl::TEXT, 2) AS "Dept",`

Comment: right is an function. You can have many ways  query function signature (input,output). see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347282/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-functions-stored-in-the-database-of-a-particular-sch

Comment: Right() is a string function, not a numerical function.

Comment: @Perk8 What do you mean by "*the last two characters*" from a `numeric` value?